# jQuery mouseenter and mouseleave handler not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseevent

I have been trying desperately to solve my problem and I just don't find the mistake in my code. So what I am programming is a slider which works with jQuery and I had everything precisely as I wanted it but then I made some completely irrelevant changes and it didn't work any more. My issue is that (as you can see in the jsfiddle) the arrows to navigate the slider don't (always) show up. They only show up at the very end of the Interval (see jsfiddle). Am I doing something wrong with the `.mouseenter` and `.mouseleave`-handlers?
Would you recommend using the `.hover-handler?

Thanks in advance

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VincentBS/ogm967bz

And if that helps: [Here](http://dev.hvgg.de) is the website the slider is programmed for

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


 hideArrows();
 hideImages();

 $(".back").click(function(){prevImage()});

 $(".pre").click(function(){nextImage()});

 $("#slider").mouseenter(function(){ 
  //showArrows();
  $(".back").show();
  $(".pre").show();
 })

 $("#slider").mouseleave(function(){ 
  //hideArrows();
  $(".back").hide();
  $(".pre")  .hide();
 })

 start();

});

function hideArrows(){

 $(".back").hide();
 $(".pre")  .hide();
}

function showArrows(){

 $(".back").show();
 $(".pre")  .show();
}

function hideImages(){

 $("#2").hide();
 $("#3").hide();
 $("#4").hide();
 $("#5").hide();
}

function start(){
    
    // save when we started for calculating progress
    var startedAt = Date.now();
    
    // set animation bounds
    var startValue = 1;
    var endValue   = 100;

    // figure out how much change we have over the whole animation
    var delta = endValue - startValue;

    // Animation function, to run at 60 fps.
    t = setInterval(function(){
        
        // How far are we into the animation, on a scale of 0 to 1.
        var progress = (Date.now() - startedAt) / 5000;
        
        // If we passed 1, the animation is over so clean up.
        if (progress > 1) {
         nextImage();   
        }
        
    }, 1000 / 60);

}

function prevImage(){ 

 var id = document.getElementsByClassName("activeslider")[0].id;
 var next = parseInt(id) - 1;
 if(next < 1){next = 5}
 next = "#" + next.toString();
 id = "#" + id.toString();
 $(id).removeClass("activeslider").fadeOut();
 $(next).addClass("activeslider").fadeIn();
 clearInterval(t);
 start();
}

function nextImage(){ 

 var id = document.getElementsByClassName("activeslider")[0].id;
 var next = parseInt(id) + 1;
 if(next > 5){next = 1}
 next = "#" + next.toString();
 id = "#" + id.toString();
 $(id).removeClass("activeslider").fadeOut();
 $(next).addClass("activeslider").fadeIn();
 clearInterval(t);
 start();
}
```

```css
#slider {

 float: left;
 width: 700px;
 height: 233px;
}

.back, .pre {

 background-color: #EB5A00;
 opacity: 1;
 margin-top: 92px;
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 25px;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 12.5px 7.5px;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 1001;

}

.back {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.pre {
 float: right;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

#slider, .back, .pre {
 -webkit-user-drag: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 user-drag: none;
}

.sliderimage {
 width: 100%;
}

#slider img {
 position: absolute;
 width: 700px;
 -webkit-user-drag: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 user-drag: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
    <img class="sliderimage activeslider" src="http://dev.hvgg.de/file_upload/data15749.jpg" id="1" />
    <img class="sliderimage" src="http://dev.hvgg.de/file_upload/data15750.jpg" id="2" />
    <img class="sliderimage" src="http://dev.hvgg.de/file_upload/data15751.jpg" id="3" />
    <img class="sliderimage" src="http://dev.hvgg.de/file_upload/data15752.jpg" id="4" />
    <img class="sliderimage" src="http://dev.hvgg.de/file_upload/data15753.jpg" id="5" />
    <span class="back">&#9664;</span>
 <span class="pre">&#9654;</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position problem I have change some css property

```
    #slider {

    float: left;
    width: 700px;
    height: 233px;
  position: relative;
}

.back, .pre {

    background-color: #EB5A00;
    opacity: 1;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 25px;
  position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12.5px 7.5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1001;

}

.back {
     left: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    top: 50%;
}

.pre {
      margin-right: 10px;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
}

#slider, .back, .pre {
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-drag: none;
}

.sliderimage {
    width: 100%;
}

#slider img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 700px;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-drag: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ogm967bz/1/

Answer (score 0):

I have tweaked your CSS a bit of `.back, .pre`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


 hideArrows();
 hideImages();

 $(".back").click(function(){prevImage()});

 $(".pre").click(function(){nextImage()});

 $("#slider").mouseenter(function(){ 
  //showArrows();
  $(".back").show();
  $(".pre").show();
 })

 $("#slider").mouseleave(function(){ 
  //hideArrows();
  $(".back").hide();
  $(".pre")  .hide();
 })

 start();

});

function hideArrows(){

 $(".back").hide();
 $(".pre")  .hide();
}

function showArrows(){

 $(".back").show();
 $(".pre")  .show();
}

function hideImages(){

 $("#2").hide();
 $("#3").hide();
 $("#4").hide();
 $("#5").hide();
}

function start(){
    
    // save when we started for calculating progress
    var startedAt = Date.now();
    
    // set animation bounds
    var startValue = 1;
    var endValue   = 100;

    // figure out how much change we have over the whole animation
    var delta = endValue - startValue;

    // Animation function, to run at 60 fps.
    t = setInterval(function(){
        
        // How far are we into the animation, on a scale of 0 to 1.
        var progress = (Date.now() - startedAt) / 5000;
        
        // If we passed 1, the animation is over so clean up.
        if (progress > 1) {
         nextImage();   
        }
        
    }, 1000 / 60);

}

function prevImage(){ 

 var id = document.getElementsByClassName("activeslider")[0].id;
 var next = parseInt(id) - 1;
 if(next < 1){next = 5}
 next = "#" + next.toString();
 id = "#" + id.toString();
 $(id).removeClass("activeslider").fadeOut();
 $(next).addClass("activeslider").fadeIn();
 clearInterval(t);
 start();
}

function nextImage(){ 

 var id = document.getElementsByClassName("activeslider")[0].id;
 var next = parseInt(id) + 1;
 if(next > 5){next = 1}
 next = "#" + next.toString();
 id = "#" + id.toString();
 $(id).removeClass("activeslider").fadeOut();
 $(next).addClass("activeslider").fadeIn();
 clearInterval(t);
 start();
}
```

```css
#slider {

 float: left;
 width: 700px;
 height: 233px;
}

.back, .pre {

 background-color: #EB5A00;
 opacity: 1;
 top: 92px; /* Chnages here */
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 25px;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 12.5px 7.5px;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 1001;
    position:absolute; /* Chnages here */

}

.back {
 float: left;
 left: 10px; /* Chnages here */
}

.pre {
 float: right;
 right: 10px; /* Chnages here */
}

#slider, .back, .pre {
 -webkit-user-drag: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 user-drag: none;
}

.sliderimage {
 width: 100%;
}

#slider img {
 position: absolute;
 width: 700px;
 -webkit-user-drag: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 user-drag: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
    <img class="sliderimage activeslider" src="http://dev.hvgg.de/file_upload/data15749.jpg" id="1" />
    <img class="sliderimage" src="http://dev.hvgg.de/file_upload/data15750.jpg" id="2" />
    <img class="sliderimage" src="http://dev.hvgg.de/file_upload/data15751.jpg" id="3" />
    <img class="sliderimage" src="http://dev.hvgg.de/file_upload/data15752.jpg" id="4" />
    <img class="sliderimage" src="http://dev.hvgg.de/file_upload/data15753.jpg" id="5" />
    <span class="back">&#9664;</span>
 <span class="pre">&#9654;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That was easy :) and probably that was what I changed because I had some formatting problems before

Comment: @V.Boersch-Supan see the updated answer. I have added the comment `/* Chnages here */` in 4 lines which i have modified.

Comment: in my case the `position`-tag of the `.back` and `.pre` arrows must be relative because the slider is not filling the whole width of the website. But thanks anyway

Comment: Any way it is `left:10px` or `right:10px`, it won't create any issue.

Comment: Yes, but if you set the position to absolute (on the website, not on the fiddle) the arrows are at the border of your screen and not at the border of the slider.

Comment: There is a simple way aroud for that and that is `position:relative` to the slider.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I said in my second comment. But never mind.

Answer (score 0):

Refer : http://jsfiddle.net/ogm967bz/8/

add the following css in the file

```
position:relative;
```

under the

```
.back, .pre {
background-color: #EB5A00;
opacity: 1;
margin-top: 92px;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 25px;
text-align: center;
padding: 12.5px 7.5px;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 1001;
cursor: pointer;
position:relative;
```

}